# How access value of double relation in laravel 5.7? order > history > statur lang

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i would like to display latest order status name from database but i have a problem with displaying data. Here is my code:

**OrderController**

```
    class OrderController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $orders = Order::with('shippingAddress', 'billingAddress', 'carrier', 'payment', 'status')->limit(300)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

        }
}
```

**OrderModel (cutted)**

```
public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Ss\Models\OrderHistory','id_order', 'id')
            ->orderBy('date_add', 'DESC')
            ->limit(1)
            ->with('statusLanguage');
    }
```

**OrderHistory model**

```
class OrderHistory extends Model
{
    protected $table="order_history";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function statusLanguage(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Ss\Models\StatusLanguage', 'id_status', 'id_status');
    }
}
```

How i tried to display:

```
{{ $order->status()->statusLanguage()->name ?? 'No status' }}
{{ $order->status()->statusLanguage->name ?? 'No status' }}
{{ $order->status->statusLanguage->name ?? 'No status' }}
```

Each time result was error like "Property [statusLanguage] does not exist on this collection instance." or similar.

When i try to **dd($order->status)** it show returned relation with data what i needed:
[image]

So where is mistake?

Comment: are you printing the data without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the `statusLanguage` from a collection of OrderHistory instances instead of from a single instance.  Try `$order->status[0]->statusLanguage->name`.

Comment: Yes, You are right!  When i tried to foreach (@cheran suggestion) it showed some json data: {"id":28698,"id_order":11003,"id_status":18,"id_employee":0,"date_add":"2019-02-12 21:13:23","status_language":{"id_status":18,"id_lang":3,"name":"PayU"}} I thought  that i can display text directly (because i should be one row/one column always)

Comment: @MarekKaliszuk If you only want one row, you should maybe alter your code, because you created a relationship where multiple results are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to acces a Collection of models as a single object.

You could do the following in your blade file:

```
@foreach($order->status as $status)
    {{ $status->statusLanguage->name ?? 'No status' }}
@endforeach
```

More information about [relationships with eloquent here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships).